# npm install errors with angular project downloaded from github

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

Bear with me. This is my first time posting a question.

What I did: cloned repo went into main folder and used npm install.

```
npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@5.2.11: Package no longer supported. Use @angular/common 
instead, see https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp

npm WARN deprecated angularfire2@5.4.2: AngularFire has moved, we're now @angular/fire 

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended 
for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

npm WARN deprecated angular-sortablejs@2.7.0: angular-sortablejs was renamed to ngx-sortablejs, please use the latter one, only ngx-sortablejs will be updated in the future

npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

npm WARN deprecated bfj-node4@5.3.1: Switch to the `bfj` package for fixes and new features!

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated @google-cloud/functions-emulator@1.0.0-beta.6: Deprecating in favor of 
the Functions Framework and firebase-tools. See https://github.com/googlearchive/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/327

npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist 
>3.0 config used in other tools.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.81.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.

npm WARN deprecated json3@3.3.2: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3       

npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).

npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).

npm WARN deprecated sntp@1.0.9: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.

npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\genod\programing\tonysProjects\TAHelper\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: most of the output is just warnings as it seems this is an older project. to fix the error can you try to update grpc to the latest version?

Comment: I have the latest version i believe

Comment: how would I check?

Comment: you can run npm outdated to check for any outdated versions on the projects packages. In this instance I do believe it is not compatible with the latest node version so you can run npm i grpc@latest

Comment: i get this error: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Comment: this might be due to a bad version in your package-lock.json file, can you try to remove this file and run the command again